# Qual a diferença em utilizar a GDS32.dll e a fbclient.dll, e entre a extensão .fdb e .GDB no Firebird?

Tags: firebird

Falando-se do `SGDB` `Firebird`, ao usar a biblioteca `GDS32.dll`, fora a compatibilidade com bancos criados pelo `Interbase`, **existem outras diferenças ao usar a `fbclient.dll`?**

**Existe diferença entre criar bancos com a extensão `.fdb` ao invés de usar a `.GDB`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Firebird é um SGBD open source que surgiu quando a versão 6.0 do Interbase teve seu código aberto para a comunidade sob a licença IPL, Interbase Public License. Entretanto as novas versões do Interbase permaneceram com seu código fonte fechado e a partir de então Firebird e Interbase passaram a ser coisas distintas, ou seja, o Firebird foi um fork do Interbase 6.0.

Por esse motivo a maioria das coisas são compatíveis entre eles, entretanto recomendo sempre usar o `fbclient.dll`, pois você pode ser surpreendido em alguma situação que os BDs acabaram se diferenciando.

Quanto a extensão, não afeta no funcionamento naquilo que depende do SGBD, o bom é usar o `.fdb` para deixar claro que o banco de dados que está usando é o Firebird e não o Interbase. No que depende do sistema operacional existe um incomodo quando se está trabalhando com o Windows, já que a partir do Windows XP e seu o sistema de recuperação a extensão `.gdb` faz parte de uma lista de extensões que são copiadas toda vez que o arquivo é alterado. Como o Firebird modifica o arquivo a cada transação se o banco de dados for muito grande o desempenho pode ser altamente prejudicado.

Fontes: [ClubeDelphi](http://www.devmedia.com.br/firebird-poderoso-leve-gratuito-e-open-source-revista-clubedelphi-135-parte-1/22887) e [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq353/)

Answer (score 1):

Quando se instala o firebird ele oferece a copia da dll como GDS32.ddl apenas para fins de compatibilidades, ambas são a mesma coisa e portanto não existe diferença.

Quanto a extensão, também não faz diferença. Em cada empresa que trabalhei eles utilizavam uma extensão diferente para o banco e raramente a padrão.