# Migração, Delphi e Firebird. Qual a forma correta de lidar com a questão de encode?

Tags: delphi, firebird, encode

Tenho um projeto em Delphi 7 que faz uso do Firebird.
Penso em migrar essa aplicação para uma versão Delphi XE*.

Porém, sabemos que a partir do Delphi 2009 o padrão de String é Unicode e não mais ANSI.

Minha base do Firebird foi criada com padrão ANSI, e tanto que o sistema grava e lê dados do banco de dados sem problemas de compatibilidade de caracteres.
Por padrão o Firebird usa WIN1252 como encode, que acredito ser similar ou o próprio ANSI.

Em projetos com SQL Server e Entity Framework nos aconselham a não usar Unicode porque ocupa mais espaço. Ok, e não temos problema com isso. Configura-se então para VARCHAR.

Penso em pegar todo o schema do banco de dados e recriar a base em um padrão novo, inclusive ainda está em GDB mesmo usando Firebird 2.5, mas não usar um padrão Unicode nas colunas do tipo texto no banco? Usar que tipo?

Porque eu não quero ter que tratar todo o sistema para usar o tipo AnsiString, mas sim o próprio String.

Qual seria a forma correta de tratar essa situação?
Grato

Comment: É uma dúvida que tenho, excelente pergunta!

Comment: Sobre o banco, aqui tem um pouco de informação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13708/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-em-utilizar-a-gds32-dll-e-a-fbclient-dll-e-entre-a-extens%C3%A3o-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode continuar usando WIN1252 no Firebird. Não fará nenhuma diferença nesta questão.

Comment: E não gera conflito de caracteres? Exemplo, posso fazer algo como: `q.FieldByName('Field').AsString := 'Ü';` que não irá causar um problema de compatibilidade de tipos? Ao invés de ter que fazer `q.FieldByName('Field').AsAnsiString := 'Ü';` ? Quem se encarrega de tratar esses tipos, os drivers do banco? Grato por sua resposta!

Comment: @JamesTK Quando utilizar `asString` estará utilizando um tipo unicode, que com certeza possui o caracter `Ü`. O componente de acesso ao banco de dados **deveria** fazer a conversão. Mas se você tem alguma dúvida específica, seria melhor construir um exemplo de código.